# How to get the POST TITLE using the POST ID?

Tags: php, database, html, code

I made a page with several POST IDs that I get from the Table of a plugin.

Now the page is showing like:
3249
3250
3251
3252 
(Post IDS)

I wanna show the title of those IDs like

3249 - POST TITLE OF 3249
3250 - POST TITLE OF 3250

etc...

Answer (score 2):

WordPress has a ton of the [`get_the_*()` functions](https://developer.wordpress.org/?s=get_the_&post_type%5B%5D=wp-parser-function) which you can pass an ID and return a value you're looking for. In this case you can call [`get_the_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/) which returns the title of a post. An example could look like:

```
echo get_the_title( 3249 );
```

Comment: Hey @howdy_mcgee! Thanks for the msg, I used this:
<?php  {  echo get_the_title($test_id ); }?>

(test_id is what I use to get the Post-ID)

But for some reason its showing the current page title instead of the one with the ID

Comment: How are you defining the value of `$test_id`?  Can you show us that code?

Comment: @PhilipKav I don't see the purpose of the brackets in your code `{...}`. It's also unclear what `$test_id` is.

Comment: Thanks guys! Got it to work, here is the Code:

$user_id = $post->post_author;
$table_name = "DB";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$table_name." WHERE user_id = ".intval($user_id);
$result = $wpdb->get_results($sql);  
 if(!empty($result))                      
{    
    foreach($result as $row) {
echo get_the_title($row->test_id) . " | ". $row->score. "/100 " . 
          "<a href=/test/".  $row->test_id ."/?result=".$row->id." > RESULT</a><br>";
        
   
The only problem I m having is that I m trying to get the SLUG instead of the $row->test_id to work with the SLUG permalink.

Comment: Please update the question with this code. It’s not readable there.